# By what criteria is a question considered "well-received"?

Tags: support

The notion of a "well-received" question is mentioned in several places on EL&U – such as in the qualifications for the "Curious", "Inquisitive", and "Socratic" [Question Badges](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges) – but I've been unable to find the specific criteria by which a question is adjudged to be "well-received". (I searched both [Meta.English](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) and the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).) What are those criteria?

Comment: ["A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a score > 0."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges)

Comment: @Mitch: Aha! Thank you! For the benefit of others who may have the same question, would you please convert your comment into an Answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked it up on meta:

> "A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a score > 0."(

From meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges

Comment: I guess that means this question is *not* "well-received" (having no upvotes as I write).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Well, feel free to add one! =)

Comment: @jdmc: Out of pure devilment (and to make my earlier comment still reasonably credible! :) I've just added my downvote (to one existing downvote masked by two upvotes). Actually, I *can* justify saying it's not a very useful question. The usage only arises in the context of an SE meta.meta proposal to award badges to people who ask "good" questions. But the proposal [obviously ain't gonna fly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228845/153229), so the proposed definition isn't really relevant to anything.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Forgive me, I'm a bit confused. The question arose for me when I viewed the list of available [Question Badges](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges) here at EL&U, and those three (Curious, Inquisitive, Socratic) are right there—not just proposed, but implemented. Doesn't that make the definition of "well-received" relevant?

Comment: You're right - I didn't look very far last time around. I see now the usage *does* exist and have a clearly-defined meaning for current contexts. So I've reversed my downvote (which as I said, was mainly for "not-very-justifiable" reasons anyway! :)